# How to write to file in separate function

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to get my program to write in a separate function than the main function, and I'm having a good deal of trouble. Here is a simplified version of my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void writeToFile(int x)
{
    outputFile << x << endl;
}

int main()
{
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("program3data.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    writeToFile(i);
}
outputFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Imagine what would happen in very large programs if every variable you created anywhere was usable everywhere. Adding anything at all would be a huge risk due to conflicting names. Even smaller programs would have to be aware of all variables created in the headers (standard or not) they use.

Comment: This won't compile as outputFile is not within the scope of writeTofile().  Place it in a class, pass it as a parameter, or (yuck) make it global.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `writeToFile` function is trying to use the `outputFile` variable which is in a different scope.  You can pass the output stream to the function and that should work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void writeToFile(ofstream &outputFile, int x)
{
    outputFile << x << endl;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open("program3data.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        writeToFile(outputFile, i);
    }
    outputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your sub-function aware of `outputFile`.  As written, that variable only exists inside of the 'main' function.  You can change your function signature to:

```
void writeToFile(int x, ofstream of)
```

and call it like:

```
writeToFile(i, outputFile);
```

This will pass the variable to the sub-function so that it can be used in that scope as well.

Comment: Note that streams are not copyable; use `ofstream &of`